# javascript clearInterval not working on array function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

```js
var intervalHandles = [];

function instanceLoopTimer(url,instance, time, id) { 
 if (id in intervalHandles) {
  clearInterval(intervalHandles[id]);
  intervalHandles[id] = 0;
 }
 intervalHandles[id] = setInterval(function() { 
  myFuction(); 
 }, time);
}
```

I created this function so that it can loop itself, the function work perfectly the first time you run but the second time i run with the same values, it seem to go in a infinite loop

I think that the clearInterval is not being triggered so that when i rerun the same instance it goes in the loop, can someone help me out please

Comment: Are you wanting it so that if you call it a second time it stops the loop completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use and object for the `var intervalHanldes = {}`
   When you use an array, you can't use strings as indexes.
2. If you set the prop to 0 the `in` operator will find it, so its better to use `delete`

```js
var intervalHandles = {}; // should be an object!

function instanceLoopTimer(url,instance, time, id) { 
  if (id in intervalHandles) {
    clearInterval(intervalHandles[id]);
    delete intervalHandles[id];
  }

  intervalHandles[id] = setInterval(myFuction, time);
}
```

Comment: but after it delete interval recreate the setInterval

Comment: what do you actually want to archive?

Comment: so for example the second time around i want to change the time value

Comment: for example first time i call instanceLoopTimer('www.google.com',1,60000,myid) and second time instanceLoopTimer('www.google.com',1,360000,myid) so that a user change the frequency

Comment: intervalHandles should be an object

Comment: you used an array, instead of object, this is why it did't worked ;)

Comment: opppss was my problem actually the function was working fine in the first place but the second call i put it 1millisecond, I guess i am tired, thank you :)

Comment: upgraded my function with the delete intervalHandles[id] also, thanks for the tip

Comment: np, glad I could help you ;)

Comment: @webdeb Update your description to match your updated code for future viewers :)

Comment: Cool; I'll give it +1!

Answer (score 0):

Your code *does* work. If you call the function a second time it will stop the original interval, set it to 0, and then will start a new interval in it's place:

Demo:

```js
var intervalHandles = [];

var myFunction = function() {
  console.log('myFunction was called, 1 second interval');
};

function instanceLoopTimer(url, instance, time, id) {
  if (id in intervalHandles) {
    clearInterval(intervalHandles[id]);
    intervalHandles[id] = 0;
  }
  intervalHandles[id] = setInterval(function() {
    myFunction();
  }, time);
}

instanceLoopTimer(null, null, 1000, 1);

setTimeout(function() {
  myFunction = function() {
    console.log('new myFunction was called, 0.5 second interval');
  };

  instanceLoopTimer(null, null, 500, 1);
}, 5000);
```

If what you are wanting is for the second call to just completely stop the interval and not restart it, you can put a `return` in your if statement:

Demo:

```js
var intervalHandles = [];

var myFunction = function() {
  console.log('myFunction was called, 1 second interval');
};

function instanceLoopTimer(url, instance, time, id) {
  if (id in intervalHandles) {
    clearInterval(intervalHandles[id]);
    intervalHandles[id] = 0;
    return;
  }
  intervalHandles[id] = setInterval(function() {
    myFunction();
  }, time);
}

instanceLoopTimer(null, null, 1000, 1);

setTimeout(function() {
  myFunction = function() {
    console.log('This should not be called');
  };

  instanceLoopTimer(null, null, 1000, 1);
}, 5000);
```

It is worth noting that if you call it a 3rd time and expect the interval to start again, it wont. This is because your id will remain in your `intervalHandles` array unless you insert `delete intervalHandles[id]` above that return statement like so:

```js
var intervalHandles = [];

var myFunction = function() {
  console.log('myFunction was called, 1 second interval');
};

function instanceLoopTimer(url, instance, time, id) {
  if (id in intervalHandles) {
    clearInterval(intervalHandles[id]);
    delete intervalHandles[id];
    return;
  }
  intervalHandles[id] = setInterval(function() {
    myFunction();
  }, time);
}

instanceLoopTimer(null, null, 1000, 1);

setTimeout(function() {
  myFunction = function() {
    console.log('This should not be called');
  };

  instanceLoopTimer(null, null, 1000, 1);
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
  myFunction = function() {
    console.log('The interval is alive again!');
  };

  instanceLoopTimer(null, null, 1000, 1);
}, 10000);
```